# Samsung S9+ and RenderScript Intrinsics

Tags: java, android, c++, image-processing, android-renderscript

I use this Script to convert YUV_420_888 images to Bitmap. Everything works fine on my Samsung S8. I tried the RenderScript on my S9+ and the result is a black Bitmap. No error, no warning just a black Bitmap. I updated the S9+ to Android Pie but everything is still black. I really can`t explain what is wrong with the S9+ devices...

```
        int W = mImage.getWidth();
        int H = mImage.getHeight();

        Image.Plane Y = mImage.getPlanes()[0];
        Image.Plane U = mImage.getPlanes()[1];
        Image.Plane V = mImage.getPlanes()[2];

        int Yb = Y.getBuffer().remaining();
        int Ub = U.getBuffer().remaining();
        int Vb = V.getBuffer().remaining();

        byte[] data = new byte[Yb + Ub + Vb];

        Y.getBuffer().get(data, 0, Yb);
        V.getBuffer().get(data, Yb, Vb);
        U.getBuffer().get(data, Yb + Vb, Ub);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(Main2Activity.this);
        ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

        Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(data.length);
        Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(W).setY(H);
        Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        final Bitmap bmpout = Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        in.copyFromUnchecked(data);

        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
        yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);
        out.copyTo(bmpout);
```

**Edit:**I changed the resolution of my mImage to 2.960 x 1.440 Pixel and received some crashes. While the App was crashing I installed the App again and while crashing the App showed the Bitmaps. I think the problem is not the code. I think the S9+ has some problem running renderscript properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the S9+ had problems with a TextureView which I placed over an ImagView. After removing the TextureView the App worked just fine.